# spark: value histogram is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Option[Any]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, histogram, rdd

I'm new to spark and scala and I've come up with a compile error with scala:
Let's say we have a rdd, which is a map like this:

```
val rawData = someRDD.map{
    //some ops
    Map(
    "A" -> someInt_var1  //Int
    "B" -> someInt_var2  //Int
    "C" -> somelong_var  //Long
    )
}
```

Then, I want to get histogram info of these vars. So, here is my code:

```
rawData.map{row => row.get("A")}.histogram(10)
```

And the compile error says:

> value histogram is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Option[Any]]

I'm wondering why `rawData.map{row => row.get("A")}` is `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Option[Any]]` and how to transform it to rdd[Int]?
I have tried like this:

```
rawData.map{row => row.get("A")}.map{_.toInt}.histogram(10)
```

But it compiles fail:

> value toInt is not a member of Option[Any]

I'm totally confused and seeking for help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `Option` because `Map.get` returns an option; `Map.get` returns None if the key doesn't exist in the `Map`; And `Option[Any]` is also related to the miscellaneous data types of the Map's Value, you have both Int and Long, in my case it returns `AnyVal` instead of `Any`;

A possible solution is use `getOrElse` to get rid of Option by providing a default value when the key doesn't exist, and if you are sure `A`'s value is always a int, you can convert it from `AnyVal` to `Int` using `asInstanceOf[Int]`;

A simplified example as follows:

```
val rawData = sc.parallelize(Seq(Map("A" -> 1, "B" -> 2, "C" -> 4L)))

rawData.map(_.get("A"))
// res6: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Option[AnyVal]] = MapPartitionsRDD[9] at map at <console>:27

rawData.map(_.getOrElse("A", 0).asInstanceOf[Int]).histogram(10)
// res7: (Array[Double], Array[Long]) = (Array(1.0, 1.0),Array(1))
```